# Transaction error with Ibm-was and spring

Tags: java, spring, ibm-was

I'm getting the following error:
 com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWException: java.lang.VerifyError: com/ibm/websphere/uow/UOWSynchronizationRegistry.registerInterposedSynchronization.

I'm using:

`<bean id="transactionManager"    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" />`

and

```
<properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
            value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
            value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory" />

</properties>
```

Stack:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWException: java.lang.VerifyError: com/ibm/websphere/uow/UOWSynchronizationRegistry.registerInterposedSynchronization(Ljavax/transaction/Synchronization;)V
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(UOWManagerImpl.java:1137)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(UOWManagerImpl.java:630)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:281)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working now.
I removed from the package the following jars:

```
jta.jar e activemq-all
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what the above line does and where you should run it?